# Android ffmpeg with opus support

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, opus

I'm following [this](https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk) tutorial, with some changes, i want add the [opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/) support, I think adding the option `--enable-libopus` is all i need but no, when I try compile with the shell as follow I'm getting the error:

configure.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export ANDROID_NDK=/home/ademar/android-ndk-r9
export TOOLCHAIN=$(pwd)/temp/ffmpeg
export SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/
$ANDROID_NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 --install-dir=$TOOLCHAIN

export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar

CFLAGS="-O3 -Wall -mthumb -pipe -fpic -fasm \
  -finline-limit=300 -ffast-math \
  -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing \
  -fmodulo-sched -fmodulo-sched-allow-regmoves \
  -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack \
  -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ \
  -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ \
  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG"

EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"

FFMPEG_FLAGS="--prefix=/tmp/ffmpeg/build \
  --target-os=linux \
  --arch=arm \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-symver \
  --disable-doc \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --disable-ffmpeg \
  --disable-ffprobe \
  --disable-ffserver \
  --disable-avdevice \
  --disable-avfilter \
  --disable-encoders  \
  --disable-muxers \
  --disable-filters \
  --disable-devices \
  --disable-everything \
  --enable-protocols  \
  --enable-parsers \
  --enable-demuxers \
  --disable-demuxer=sbg \
  --enable-decoders \
  --enable-bsfs \
  --disable-network \
  --enable-swscale  \
  --enable-asm \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-version3"

cd ffmpeg
./configure $FFMPEG_FLAGS --extra-cflags="$CFLAGS $EXTRA_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS"
```

the error:

```
ERROR: opus not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest version from Git. If the latest version fails, report the problem to the ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net. Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help solving the problem.
```

if want i can post the `config.log` content, but it is big.

on folder ffmpeg I have a git clone from source.ffmpeg.org on branch `release/1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest release of ffmpeg now includes the opus codecs. You no longer need to include libopus with ffmpeg. Hope this helps anyone else looking into this.

Comment: wow it seems very good, but here https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1 still informing that "Requires the presence of the libopus headers and library during configuration. You need to explicitly configure the build with --enable-libopus." maybe it is just deprecated documentation, do you have the commit where libopus was included?

Comment: @ademar111190 Since FFmpeg 2.3 opus decoding support has been added. I'm not sure if encoding is available however decoding works. I'm using official release FFmpeg 2.5.

Comment: The `opus` encoder shipped with FFmpeg is not good and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you build and install libopus before you build ffmpeg. Just adding the option to enable tells ffmpeg to allow opus but it does not mean your system has libopus already installed. That is why configure is complaining.

Install libopus. See http://www.opus-codec.org/ for details on how to download and build.

Comment: Undestood, if I Already installed the opus library, how can I pass it for ffmpeg?

Comment: Then it should find it as part of configure. If not there will be a option to give directory path in configure. type ./configure --help to get list of options and one of them will be for giving path to libraries.